# What performance gain from GPU with matlab?

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu

I am thinking about asking my boss for a good GPU, in order to perform computing with matlab parallel processing toolbox.
However, after some simple tests on a colleague's computer, on a NVidia Quadro 600. I get very poor performance gain (between 1x and 2x).

I am especially interested in doing convolutions on n-d arrays.

Do someone have a similar experience, doing computing with `gpuArray` and so on?

What performance gain can I expect?

What GPU model should I buy (less than 1000$, hopefully less than 400$)?

Comment: Can you show which functions from matlab you will use?

Comment: There seems to be several questions here. Of them "What GPU should I buy?" is off-topic and too-localized in my view. "What experience do you have?" seems very chatty and open-ended too.

Comment: As I said in my question, I am especially interested by convolutions, especiallay `convn` and `conv2`

Comment: @awoodland I think this might not the best fit for SE, but it is a valid question, for people in the same situation as the OP, this question makes sense. Although I didn't know matlab has gpu support. What a mess it would be!

Comment: @oli The FFT and iFFT functions also support `gpuArray`.  If your kernels are larger than ~20x20 you can gain a lot from doing convolutions that way (with or without GPU).

Comment: convn, conv2, fft, ifft, and many other functions are supported by Jacket.  In general, Jacket supports more functions than gpuArray.  The full list is here:  http://wiki.accelereyes.com/wiki/index.php/Function_List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of the `gpuArray` in MATLAB is driven by several factors:

- Whether your problem runs well on the GPU in the first place
- How many CUDA cores you've got in your device, generally speaking the more the better
- Whether you're using a device which has the enhanced double-precision performance (such as the recent Quadro/Tesla devices of compute capability >= 2)
- Which release of MATLAB you're using - R2011b is significantly better performing than R2010b.

Here's an example of some benchmarks on the excellent 'Walking Randomly' blog: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3634 . These show the kinds of speedup one might expect in reasonable applications - i.e. ~5x to 10x is plausible, much more than that is rare.

(If you'd like to see one of those rare examples, the Mandelbrot set on the GPU programmed using `gpuArray`s and `arrayfun` runs about 1500x faster than the CPU: http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/parallel-computing/paralleldemo_gpu_mandelbrot/paralleldemo_gpu_mandelbrot.html?product=DW )

Answer (score 1):

A Quadro 400 only has 48 cores compared to the GeForce 480 that has 480 cores and the GeForce 580 that has 512 cores. These both also run at higher-clocks too so you can expect more than 10x performance gain when memory access is not the limiting factor.

I've not used GPUs to accelerate MATLAB but I have PCs I use for GPU (CUDA) dev every day. One has a Quadro FX5800 + GeForce 480, the other a GeForce 580. To the best of my knowledge, you will get no benefit from a workstation card versus a GeForce. So save some $$$ and get a GF480 or GF580.

This thread appears to have a CUDA accelerated conv function that is apparently 50x faster:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20220
I'm not sure what MATLAB has out-of-the-box these days.

Hope that helps! GPUs can be great for accelerating many tasks. But performance gains may take some chasing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently researching this same topic. One thing I'm seeing is that low- and mid-range graphics cards are intended for gaming and consequently optimized for FP32 performance. Their FP64 performance lags significantly as a result and may be what you're seeing. The $1k GTX Titan appears to be the starting point for serious scientific computation.